# Fragment into Activity transition

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have found bunch of answers on how to set transition between:

- Activity <--> Activity
- Fragment <--> Fragment

Example: http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/

**Question:** is it possible to set transition between a `Fragment` and an `Activity`?

---

For example, I have a `ViewPager` with a `Fragment`. I click a button in the `Fragment` and want to animate-expand it into a new `Activity`.

---

**Update:** I have `Activity` > `ViewPager` > `Fragment` > `LinearLayout` ---> that should transition into ---> `Activity` > `LinearLayout`.

**Update2:** Have been using [Shared Element Activity Transition](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition) tutorial. My `Activity > ViewPager > Fragment` element looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_entries"
            style="@style/Container.Entries"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:transitionName="from_entry_to_entries_list"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_entries"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle.Flat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

My receiving  `Activity`s element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_entries"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:transitionName="from_entry_to_entries_list">
</LinearLayout>
```

My `styles.xml`:

```
<!-- Theme: App -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

...

    <!-- Transitions: Enable window content transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <!-- Transitions: specify transitions -->
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/from_entry_to_entries_list</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/from_entry_to_entries_list</item>
```

My `from_entry_to_entries_list.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

**Problem:** Transition is shown as alpha in/out instead of `LinearLayout` being re-scaled into an `Activity`.

Comment: It is possible. It will be same as Activity transition. Use shared views if expand kind of animation required

Comment: @VishnuSP I have updated my question to point out the goal clearly.

Answer (score 1):

In this case also, it will work the same way as Activity transition with shared views.

Have a look at this tutorial : [Shared Element Activity Transition](http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition)

In your case, 
(`Activity > ViewPager > Fragment > LinearLayout`) the LinearLayout (or its child) will have the `android:transitionName="my_transition"` and the same attribute for another view in the second activity.

Comment: Well, I was using this tutorial in first place. Although I have set transition type to `changeTransform` - the transition still shows a simple alpha in/out (instead of resizing shared element). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you modified the AppTheme as given in the tutorial? Please share more info and code.

Comment: Updated my question with details.

Comment: The code looks correct.can you share the code for starting the second activity?